# Downvoting a new member

Tags: discussion, votes, new-users

I just downvoted a post (now deleted) by a new member who has a reputation of one.

Downvoting cost me some reputation, but it also cost that user some reputation, or at least it would have if that user had more than one reputation point.

What happens with that user’s reputation? When they get their first upvote, will it be worth the full ten points?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Reputation never drops below 1 and previous downvotes are not accumulated to be applied afterwards.**

Please note:

- **Downvotes help the system** automatically block people who make a habit of posting bad questions or answers.  When a new user is downvoted several times on their first few posts (the exact amounts are not disclosed), temporary blocks are applied to encourage them to improve their existing posts.
- However, new users tend to react negatively to downvotes as well as to most forms of moderation, such as closing questions.  **Please try to post a comment welcoming a new contributor** and explaining the reason for the downvote.  (It doesn't hurt to add your comment to any other welcoming comments: the more the better!)
- Generally, for the same reasons, **it is good to accompany any downvote with an explanatory comment.**  (One general exception is when you know the poster is a serial violator of site norms and you have already tried, in another thread, to explain your position.  You don't have to keep posting the same explanation only to have it be ignored again!)

Answer (score 5):

I would search for more meaningful posts at Meta. But a quick experimentation showed this:

$\bullet$ Downvote:

[image]

$\bullet$ Result:

[image]

*Waiting for $15$ minutes...*

$\bullet$ Subsequent upvote at another post:

[image]

$\bullet$ Result:

[image]

(NB: All the votes have been undone after sufficient time.)

Comment: I have done this for questions. I hope the result won't be different in case of answer with the addition that my rep would decrease.

Comment: Tip: By appending an "m" to the root names of the image links, I shrank them to a more manageable size.  Appending "s" would shrink them even more.

Comment: Thanks @whuber. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: It's an obscure thing to know.  I forget where it's documented.  I use it about once a year, but given your high level of activity I thought you might find it handy.